# logical replication initial phase

Tags: postgresql, replication, transactional-replication, data-synchronization, postgresql-12

I am about doing replication for 16 millions record. Just want to ask about the initial phase of logical replication :

1. Do I need to copy the initial table from publisher to subscriber first ? Or is it handled by the subscription ? I don't know how long will it be if it is handled by the replication process...
2. Here and some other sites too,*https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/logical-replication-postgresql-explained*, it says **"... spawn multiple table synchronization workers"** How can I spawn multiple table synchronization workers ? Which parameter is it ? None of the articles I read mention parameter for setting sync workers

thanks

Postgres 12 running on Ubuntu

Comment: The material you quote is not located at the indicated link.

Comment: yes.. sorry. But more or less the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re 1)

No, you don't need to do anything. As soon as you create the subscription, Postgres will copy the data. You can prevent the initial copy if you wanted to, by using `with (copy_data = false)` when [creating the subscription](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsubscription.html#id-1.9.3.84.6).

re 2)

Then number of background processes for logical replication isn't controlled per subscription, but system wide on the [subscriber](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-REPLICATION-SUBSCRIBER) through `max_logical_replication_workers` and `max_sync_workers_per_subscription`.

However for a single table only [a single worker](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-MAX-SYNC-WORKERS-PER-SUBSCRIPTION) will be used.

> Currently, there can be only one synchronization worker per table.

So, increasing `max_sync_workers_per_subscription` only affects the number of tables that are synchronized in parallel, not the number of workers *per table*.

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name , thanks indeed. It opens up another question : Is there any situation where the number of subscription is greater than `max_logical_replication_workers` ? What happen if it does ?